# How to pass two variables in JavaScript using thymleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using books object in thymeleaf to fetch values. I want to pass multiple values of fetched thymeleaf variables into JavaScript function on click of button.

```
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th> Number </th>
                    <th>Books</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th> Author</th>
                    <th> Add to cart</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="book: ${books}">
                    <td th:text="${book.id}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" th:value="${book.id}" name="bookid" />
                    <!-- <td><img src="${book.url}" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333"></td> -->
                    <td><img th:src="${book.url}" width="120"/>
                    </td>
                    <!-- <td th:text="${book.url}"/> -->
                    <td th:text="${book.name}" />
                    <td th:text="${book.price}" />
                    <td th:text="${book.Author}" />
                    <td><button th:onclick="'javascript:(' + ${book.id} + ');'">Add to cart</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            
        </table>
```

- List item

Comment: finally got the solution for it:                                                                                                  <td><button th:onclick="javascript:cart([[${book.id}]], [[${book.name}]],[[${book.price}]])">Add to cart</button></td>

Comment: Side note: the canonical way to do this with Thymeleaf is using a small `<form>` and doing a `POST` to the server. If you want to avoid page reloads, you can also rely on [htmx](https://htmx.org/). https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/10/04/todomvc-with-thymeleaf-and-htmx/ explains in more detail how to combine Thymeleaf and htmx (Disclaimer: I am the author of the blog post)